# C# Binary Serialization

Tags: c#, serialization, binary

I am trying to serialize and deserialize objects to/from a Byte array for network communication, I currently have an interface 'ISerialize'. However I got thinking there should be a more robust way to do this via reflection.

I've looked around a little bit at doing this using BinaryFormater, but I can't see if it will give me the control I require.

**EDIT:**

I would like to beable to decorate a class as Follows
(Where fields can be any type so long as they are a system type or are also [Serializable])

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass {

    [NonSerialized]
    SomeOtherClass _classFeild;

    [Position (0)]
    UInt16 _field1;

    [Position (14)]
    UInt32 _feild2;

    //..........
}
```

And have the following functionality,

```
void Test () {
    MyObject = new MyClass ();
    Byte[] raw;
    raw  =  Serializer.Serialize (MyClass); // Results in _field1 at raw[0,1]
                                            //            _field2 at raw[14-18]

    MyClass Deserialized  = Serializer.Deserialize<MyClass> (raw); 
}
```

where all fields are swapped to / from network order (bigendian)

---

I would also rather white list fields to be serialized rather than blacklist those not to be. So the question is, is can I do this using the Framework, or do I need to write my own implementation?

Comment: (removed my answer, as I don't think it fits your case - but I think it would be better to add the extra detail (from your comments) to the question)

Comment: Thanks for the input all the same :D

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a good fit for [BinaryWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx) and [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx).

Comment: I'm not sure that BinaryWriter gives me the functionality I'm looking for (See my edit). And indeed I am using BitConverter within ToHostOrder.

Comment: In your DeSerialize example why don't you use BitConverter.ToUInt32 rather than doing bit shift operations?

Comment: No logical reason, its an artefact from when I ported from VB6, it didn't occur to me to use BitConverter in that instance.

Answer (score 2):

[BinarySerializer](https://github.com/jefffhaynes/BinarySerializer) will do all that and more.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/). It's a great library for doing exactly what you want.  It is a third party library, however it does store the data in a well defined format that can be read by other libraries both in C# and numerous other languages.

Here is a sample of how to use it:  http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/GettingStarted

I've used it myself and was quite pleased.

Comment: I have used protobuf for a few other projects. Unfortunately the interface I am communicating with is rather fixed in its ways. (C style struct)

Answer (score 0):

I think the project I recently put on github might be just the fight for you. I claim it will be the fastest binary serializer available and it has zero overhead.  Every property is directly represented by its binary value.

Check out: https://github.com/Toxantron/CGbR#binary-datacontract-serializer

Input is right now the DataContract and DataMember attribute

```
[DataContract]
public partial class Root
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Number { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Partial[] Partials { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public IList<ulong> Numbers { get; set; }
}
```

and the generator output

```
    public byte[] ToBytes(byte[] bytes, ref int index)
    {
        // Convert Number
        Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(Number), 0, bytes, index, 4);;
        index += 4;
        // Convert Partials
        // Two bytes length information for each dimension
        Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes((ushort)(Partials == null ? 0 : Partials.Length)), 0, bytes, index, 2);
        index += 2;
        foreach(var value in Partials ?? Enumerable.Empty<Partial>())
        {
            value.ToBytes(bytes, ref index);
        }
        // Convert Numbers
        // Two bytes length information for each dimension
        Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes((ushort)(Numbers == null ? 0 : Numbers.Count)), 0, bytes, index, 2);
        index += 2;
        foreach(var value in Numbers ?? Enumerable.Empty<ulong>())
        {
            Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(value), 0, bytes, index, 8);;
            index += 8;
        }
        return bytes;
    }
```